# Selecting data between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to get a data for '20130501'

Following is the query where I put '20130501' for start date, and '20130502' for the end date.

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
                FROM TABLE A
              WHERE 
               A.DTM >= TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')
              AND A.DTM <= TO_DATE('20130502','YYYYMMDD')
```

The query above gives the data for '20130501' fine.
But now I want to put in '20130501' for both start and end date input data. Below is the query

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
                FROM TABLE A
              WHERE 
               A.DTM >= TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')
              AND A.DTM <= TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')
```

When I run the query, I get no data. I think it's because DB reads the both '20130501' as 
the same time. But I want it to be '20130501 00:00' to '20130501 24:00'

So can anyone fix the query?

Comment: can't you use the first query but with `<` instead of `<=` for the end date?

Comment: would that give me the same result logically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a day to your second date, and use `<` for the comparison;

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
FROM A
WHERE A.DTM >= TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')
  AND A.DTM <  TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')+1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3d95/11).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `>` and `<` for a date range you should use the `BETWEEN` since it is range inclusive:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.DTM BETWEEN TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20130502','YYYYMMDD');
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php

Since the solution with `TO_DATE` does not support milliseconds you can convert the `TO_DATE` into `TO_TIMESTAMP` that support the milliseconds:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
    FROM TABLE A
    WHERE A.DTM BETWEEN TO_DATE('20130501'||' 00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('20130501'||' 23:59:59.999','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

but if you need greater precision, you should work with the date difference:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
FROM TABLE A
WHERE (A.DTM - TRUNC(TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD')) BETWEEN 0 AND 1;
```

0 = A.DTM is equal to 20130501 00:00

1 = A.DTM is equal to 20130502

Comment: Won't this place the whole last minute of the day outside the range?

Comment: between is a really bad solution, you get 20130502 included in your result unless you make a scary fix. Don't use between for this problem. See @JoachimIsaksson's answer. Now you made a fix that doesn't include milliseconds

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for the tip. Added the SS for the seconds in the upper bound of the BETWEEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it is to trunc the date your are comparing with:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER
FROM TABLE A
WHERE TRUNC(A.DTM) BETWEEN TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD');
```

Edit: if you only want a single day:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.GENDER 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE TRUNC(A.DTM) = TO_DATE('20130501','YYYYMMDD');
```

Edit about performance: in my experience, TRUNC is rather fast and doesn't make a noticable difference if there are no indices. That being said: TRUNC(A.DTM) won't use indices on A.DTM. You can put an index on TRUNC(A.DTM) though.

Comment: In any case, TRUNC seems to hold up rather well as far as performance goes (in my experience at least). And yes, if you want just one day you can use =

Comment: I tested (on sqlserver) having a calculation on the date like your will slow the performance. I have no reason to think oracle is different

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Sql server does not have a TRUNC function, so I'd expect the oracle TRUNC to be faster. Whether or not is is fast enough not to make a noticable impact on a query is another matter. I did a quick search and the only things I ran into was performance issues when using columns that have indices (see last edit), but not the TRUNC function itself.

Comment: Why the down vote? The answer is correct and the question is tagged `Oracle`, why bring SQL server into the discussion.